# Can't import cv2 on Python 3.5 DLL load failed

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I've been struggling with this problem for a day and haven't been able to find a working solution. When I import cv2 with python-v, I get

```
>>> import cv2 Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
line 969, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
line 666, in _load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
line 577, in module_from_spec File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", 
line 914, in create_module File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am using Python 3.5 with Anaconda3 on windows 10 64 bit. I have gone through all the other posts on stackoverflow regarding this. Based on that here is some information of the things I have done:

1. I installed Visual Studio 14.0 from the from the VC++ 2015 standalone tools here http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
2. I deleted my old isual C++ redistributable packages and installed https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=48145. My msvcp140.dll is present here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT
3. I installed opencv python from this link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python#downloads
4. I copied the cv2.pyd package into my Lib/site-package directory

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Suggest to download `OpenCV 3.2.0` for `Python 3.5` either Windows `32-bit` or `64-bit` form this [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) website. Look for file with suffix as `opencv_python‑3.2.0+contrib‑cp35‑cp35m` for your case. The `+contrib` is the ones with opencv_contrib modules.

Then type below command to install the binary from your location drive:

- `pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0+contrib‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl` (32-bit
  version) or
- `pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0+contrib‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl` (64-bit version)

Before install this binary, make ensure the previous installation is completely removed or you may create a new `conda env` to install it. If it's successfully installed, it would be showed up in `conda list`.  Then you can check its version by `import cv2`, `print cv2.__version__`.